Book where a kid wakes up on a spaceship due to the cryosleep malfunctioning and he is stalked by a spaghetti monster
I read it awhile ago and I just remembered it I know that the guy who made it also made another book about a kid moving into a sea town and finding pirates and I think giant monsters but other then that the book was marketed towards kids one of its main colors were orange if that helps and I read it I think in 2018 maybe and I'm pretty sure the entire book has illustrations like every page.

Whoa! Are we gonna have a debate on the tenets of Pastafarianism?

Not that kind of spaghetti monster, from what I remember it looked way different then the one depicted in Pastafarianism, it was just pitch black and it looked like it was made of noodles XD
